# Load 3D Model in Unity using Assimp

Tags: unity-game-engine, assimp

is it possible to load a 3D model in Unity using Assimp? 
When i search for code samples with Assimp, i only find c++ samples using Virtual Studio. 
I can load 3D Models with AssimpNET version 3.0 ( c# wrapper) with c# code, but my goal is to use the Assimp64.dll and not the AssimpNET.dll.

thanks :)

Comment: I'm also trying to achieve this. Putting Assimp64.dll in the project root and AssimpNet.dll in Assets/Plugins lets you use the Assimp code from Unity, but still there are some unusual errors when loading models (unexplainable `NullReferenceException` after a `String.Format` for me). Please post back if you figure it out!. This post seems helpful: http://www.tesla-engine.net/forums/topic/issues-with-unity3d/

Comment: The easiest way to use Assimp and and Unity is via Assimp-net 3.0. The latest version (3.3) doesn't work and writing your own native -> managed marshalling layer would be reinventing that wheel. Here's an example (not my code!): https://github.com/akadjoker/UnityAssimp

Comment: Hi @Jenni, did you have any luck in using Assimp with Unity? If yes, that would be great if you could share your experience in that and help with some answers. Thanks.

Comment: I also looking for a code sample to load a FBX from a server location dynamically into the game scene, please can anyone help with a code sample.

Comment: Had anyone recently had success to import using assimp in Unity3d?

Comment: Note: akadjoker's unityassimp has mentioned in readme that it only works with unity4 and not 5 as there is some problem with it after API change. If some one really needs Assimp urgently for their project then there is a unitypackage called [trilib](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/modeling/trilib-unity-model-loader-package-91777) in assetstore around 25 USD as of 03-May-2018